# How can I make sweet potato fries soggy?

Tags: baking, frying, deep-frying, french-fries, sweet-potatoes

I ordered from a local restaurant recently, and their sweet potato fries tasted so similar to what I remember regular fries tasted like.

I decided that I'm going to try and make them myself, however, I can only find posts on the internet showing how to make them crunchy; it seems like more people prefer them this way.

Anyway, how do I go about doing this?

Is my only choice to make them and leave them somewhere and wait for them to get soggy over time?

Comment: I suspect that the reason that so many recipes online focus on crispy sweet potato fries is that if you try to substitute sweet potatoes in a normal French fry recipe, they end up being not so crispy.  So you might be okay with just using a potato French fry recipe

Comment: have you tried baking them in the oven?

Answer (score 5):

the reason you haven't found any recipes for soggy sweet potato fries is because of one simple fact: soggy is the default state for oven fries, unless you do something to specifically make the crispy.

So, in search of non-crispy fries, here is a list of things you could try:

- Cook at a low temperature; over 400°f makes crispy fries, so closer to 350°f will prevent crisping
- Don't overcook them; oven fries must first dry out before they get crispy, so to avoid that simply take out your fries as soon as they are cooked through
- Don't use too much oil; oil helps fries to ... "fry" ... use only a little to prevent sticking
- Steam your fries afterwards; after you take them out of the oven they will be very hot and will release steam, simply cover with tin foil ... a lid ... a pan ... anything
- Try cooking them in the microwave instead of the oven

hope this helps

p.s.
sriracha mayonnaise is a great dip for sweet potato fries

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! The question is tagged [deep-frying], not [bake].

Comment: Anastasia: it's still good advice.  It's what I would have recommended.

Comment: Hi Max. I thought about trying to steam them instead of baking them. However, the texture of sweet potatoes when I steam them can be likened to that of mashed potatoes. There's a chance I steamed them for too long. The sweet potato fries I got from the restaurant had the exact same texture as regular fries that had been left in their paper packet then left to sit in a microwave that hadn't been started. Your suggested method makes a lot of sense to me. It's like a more effectve method of what I just described. Would an electric oven affect the way they turn out when compared to a gas oven?

Comment: @AnastasiaZendaya My mistake. I should have originally added [baking] as a tag. I've corrected that now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a life hack for you:

When heating your oil, constantly poke a chopstick into the heating oil to touch the bottom of the pot/fryer. When micro bubbles begin to come out of the tip of the chopstick when you make it touch the bottom of the pot in the oil, it should be the right temperature to fry soggy fires.

If you are going to use the standard frying temperature, to make sure that your fries turn out nice and soggy, try to give each and every potato cut little to no personal space in the fryer. This will slow down the heating process and make for soggy fries.